# How to create rtf file from a Blob in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rtf, richtext

I'm trying to create a rtf from my state variables, the file is created but it's corrupted I can't open it. How can I convert string into rtf file?

[image]

```js
const Example = () => {
  const [headers, setHeaders] = React.useState(['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3']);
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState([['Content 1', 'Content 2', 'Content 3'], ['Content 4', 'Content 5', 'Content 6']])
  const [downloadUrl, setDownloadUrl] = React.useState('');
  
  
  const createDownUrl = () => {
    const fileHeaders = headers.join(' ');
    const fileContent = content.map(i => i.join(' ')).join('\r\n');
  
    const data = new Blob([`${fileHeaders}\r\n${fileContent}`]);
    setDownloadUrl(URL.createObjectURL(data))
  }
  
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => createDownUrl()}>
          Create download link
        </button>
        
        {downloadUrl && <a download={'Example.rtf'} href={downloadUrl}>Download</a>}
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  // Render it
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Example  />,
    document.getElementById("react")
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Why not `.txt` or use JSON encode and `.json`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Sorry I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: What are you trying to open the file in? You do not seem to be using an actual [RTF file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Code_syntax) for the contents so if the program you are using is expecting an rtf formatted file it wont be able to open it. Do you see the contents you stored in the file if you try to open it in a normal text program like notepad, notepad++, or other text editor?

Comment: @PatrickEvans in an rtf editor/viewer

Comment: RTF is [not a plaintext file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), simply putting text in a file and adding the extension does not make for a valid file. Instead of trying to implement the format from scratch, you'll probably want to find a library that does this for you.